# Create a seconds field in django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to create a field that only stores seconds, without the option to enter hours and seconds. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a [**`PositiveIntegerField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#positiveintegerfield) with a [**`MaxValueValidator`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/validators/#maxvaluevalidator)?

Comment: I thought it, but how do i convert the integer field into a timefield after?